# Interact with Points of Interest on Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps, point-of-interest

I am working on **Android Studio** with the **Maps Api**. On the shown map, there are markers that have been already placed by Google (see picture below).
[image]

Is there a way to interact with them by clicking to get more information (e.g. id of marker/place)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The predefined markers added by Google are called Points of Interest (POI). The GoogleMaps class provides a special listener for POIs: `GoogleMap.OnPoiClickListener`

You can find corresponding documentation in

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/reference/com/google/android/libraries/maps/GoogleMap.OnPoiClickListener

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/reference/com/google/android/libraries/maps/model/PointOfInterest

The code snippet should be something like

```
mMap.setOnPoiClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnPoiClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPoiClick(PointOfInterest poi) {
        String placeId = poi.placeId;
        //TODO: get details for place id
    });
}
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

you can use onMarkerClickListener shown below :

```js
mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {

    });
}
```

where `mMap` is an instance of `GoogleMap`

You can start reading documentation here https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/start

Comment: Hey Shahin, with markers added by me manually it is working but not with these served from google.

Comment: well, that's because these markers are not Clickable at all. actually they shouldn't even be visible to you. did you add them by code?